# How to Compare two fields in laravel and postgres

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I'm trying to query postgres db and get a SQL error every time.
The query is correct, but why does it now work?

Query

```
Apireq::where('calls','<','maxcalls')->get();
```

Error

> SQLSTATE[22P02]: invalid input syntax for integer

Field types are both set to `bigint`.

It's bizzare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use whereRaw instead of just where. It's weird, but it gets around the issue which I think is a Laravel Bug.

```
whereRaw('calls < maxcalls')
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andrew's answer is totally correct, except that it is not a bug but expected behavior.

Here's an example why:

---

```
where('foo', '=', 'bar')
```

Now there are two possibilities how Laravel could interpret (or misinterpret?) this

#### 1. Column named `bar`

"Sure you want to compare the column `foo` with `bar`. Here's your SQL:"

```
WHERE foo = bar
```

#### 2. The *value* "bar"

"Well obviously you want all the records where `foo` equals "bar". Here you go:"

```
WHERE foo = "bar"
```

---

So Laravel has to make a decision. And because a computer (without artificial intelligence at least) can't possibly know if you want to compare with a value or another column, the developers decided it should always compare with the value (probably because it is the functionality that's needed more)

And as you already know, `whereRaw` is the solution:

```
whereRaw('calls < maxcalls')
```