# Laravel: where condition based on db field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, orm

How to make a `where`clause that is based on an existing field in the database, and not on an input parameter?

```
$query = DB::table('events')
    ->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($data){ 
                $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id'); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", $data['date_end']); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', $data['date_start']); 
});
```

This works well because the where clause is based on an input parameter.
What I need is a Where clause that is based on a field that is already in the database:

Something like this:

```
$query = DB::table('events')
    ->join('events_dates', function($join) use ($data){ 
                $join->on('events.id', '=', 'events_dates.event_id'); 
                //If db field of record: recurrent == 0 then 
                    $join->where('events_dates.start_date', "<=", $data['date_end']); 
                    $join->where('events_dates.end_date', '>=', $data['date_start']); 
                /* If db field of record: "recurrent" == "1" then
                    $join->where //another query 
                */ 
});
```

Is this achievable with the laravel ORM, or should I write a native SQL query?
Haven't found a suitable answer in the docs or in existing posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use...

```
where('column1', '=', DB::raw('column2'));
```

...to use the field value instead of the string "column2".

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27506323/1903366) I further explained why.

Comment: Ok, should I use a nested where within the join clause to fulfil the requirement posed in the question? I will do some tests to see how it works out.

Comment: That's basically the question you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27707974/1903366) right? I will take a look at it and answer there if I find a solution. It's rather off topic here (considering the question title)

Comment: Yes, it refers to the same question, but I assumed that the previous question might not have been straightforward enough. Thanks for your effort, I have been searching for a few hours today but have been unable to get it right so far.

Comment: Would you please consider accepting this answer? You have to admit, it answers the question (even if it didn't help you much ;))